# Create a text file by matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to create a text file like this with Matlab but i don't know how should I  do that.

```
range(0,25e-9,0+600e-9),range(0+600e-9,1e-4,1.000000e-03),range(1.000000e-03,25e-9,1.000000e-03+600e-9),range(1.000000e-03+600e-9,1e-4,2.000000e-03),range(2.000000e-03,25e-9,2.000000e-03+600e-9),range(2.000000e-03+600e-9,1e-4,3.000000e-03)
```

for example here I want to create 6 point and I can do it by myself. But if I want create 100 point or 500 point I have to use Matlab. I wrote a code and create a matrix something like this but what I want is different. It's my code but I cant use it.....

```
clc
clear
close all

stp1=25e-9;
stp2=1e-4;
A=600e-9;
B=1e-3;

i=3;
F=zeros(i,3);

for i=1:i
    if i==1
        F(i,1)=0;
        F(i,2)=stp1;
        F(i,3)=A;
    else 
        if mod(i,2)==0
         F(i,1)=F(i-1,3);
         F(i,2)=stp2;
         F(i,3)=(i/2)*B;
        else
            F(i,1)=F(i-1,3);
            F(i,2)=stp1;
            F(i,3)=F(i,1)+A;
        end
    end
end
```

for example this is my matrix:

```
`     0.0000e+000    25.0000e-009   600.0000e-009
   600.0000e-009   100.0000e-006     1.0000e-003
     1.0000e-003    25.0000e-009     1.0006e-003`
```

I want to put them in one line and this like this:

```
`range(0.0000e+000,25.0000e-009,600.0000e-009),range(600.0000e-009,100.0000e-006,1.0000e-003),range(1.0000e-003,25.0000e-009,1.0006e-003)`
```

you know I want to add `range(A(1,1),A(1,2),A(1,3)),range(A(2,1),A(2,2),A(2,3))` to my text file.... I hope I have explained well that I want.

Comment: Have you looked into `fprintf` and `dlmwrite`?  What have you tried to write to a text file?

Comment: hmmm ... is your question about creating a _text file_ ... or about creating the matrices with the desired numbers (and then put them in a text file) ??

Comment: @SecretAgentMan @Hoki I want to create a text file like this: `range(0,25e-9,0+600e-9),range(0+600e-9,1e-4,1.000000e-03),` I can create a [i,3] matrix but i don't know how to put them in a text file like  `range(0,25e-9,0+600e-9),range(0+600e-9,1e-4,1.000000e-03),`.... I don't know how to explain.... sorry :(

Comment: Suppose you have your `m x n` matrix `A`. (1) As @Hoki asked, do you know how to create your matrix?   (2) You're wanting to write a text file from MATLAB that has matrix `A`, right? Is there a reason `dlmwrite` or `fprintf` aren't good approaches?  (3) What have you tried so far (to write a text file)?

Comment: Also, this is tagged `cell-array` but I didn't see any cell arrays in your code.  Can you explain why this tag applies?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan (1) I know how to create my matrix,and I already create it, but the problem is how to add these words to my txt file for example this is my matrix:

` 0.0000e+000    25.0000e-009   600.0000e-009 `
`600.0000e-009   100.0000e-006     1.0000e-003`
`1.0000e-003    25.0000e-009     1.0006e-003`

I want to put them in one line and this like this:

`range(0.0000e+000,25.0000e-009,600.0000e-009),range(600.0000e-009,100.0000e-006,1.0000e-003),range(1.0000e-003,25.0000e-009,1.0006e-003)`

Comment: @SecretAgentMan (2) yes, I don't know how to use these two functions  `dlmwrite` or `fprintf` you know I want to add range(A(1,1),A(1,2),A(1,3)),range(A(2,1),A(2,2),A(2,3)) to my text file.. (3) no,this is my first experience.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I though we should use  `cell-array` to add string `range(A(i,1),A(i,2),A(i,3))` to a matrix and then save it as a text file.... If you think it's extra, I can remove it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Are you wanting the physical text put into the text file or just the value (with your specified formatting)?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan  I want to create a text file like this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cLqIPztB6OFS7MqDpbAnPBiivQp-SUx0) I want to save my matrix values like this `range(a,b,c),range(e,f,g)` that `a,b,c,e,f,g` are matrix values that I create it by myself. I hope you can understand what am I saying, and I don't know how to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put some code together below to help move this along. Please comment and I can adjust (or others can post answers based on updated information).

I'm still not sure exactly what outcome you're after.

For reference, you can see examples of file I/O documentation for `dlmwrite` [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) and for `fprintf` [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). Notice you can specify the delimiter with `dlmwrite` and the exact format with `fprintf`.

```
A = [0.0000e+000    25.0000e-009   600.0000e-009;
 600.0000e-009   100.0000e-006     1.0000e-003;
 1.0000e-003    25.0000e-009     1.0006e-003];
dlmwrite('TestFile.txt',A)  % Example use of dlmwrite

B = range(A,2);             % Range of the rows of A
dlmwrite('TextFile2.txt',B)

C = cell(size(A,1),1);
fileID = fopen('TestFile3.txt','w+');
formatstr = '%12s\r\n';
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    C{k}=['range(A(' num2str(k) ',:)'];
    fprintf(fileID,formatstr,C{k});
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the TextFile2.txt or TextFile1.txt did not include any `range(.....)` you know, for example this is our matrix [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JxRdyNK_GvhXQ51-W-bkU2xTcIKLdINk) and I want to create a text file like this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cLqIPztB6OFS7MqDpbAnPBiivQp-SUx0). How can I add these strings to my text file??

Comment: @alieskandari, check the 3rd example.  is this what you're after?  I did it in column.  Changing the `formatstr` can put it in rows.

Comment: imagine we have a matrix like this `[1,2,3;4,5,6]` and I want to create a text file like this: `SecretAgentMan(1,2,3), SecretAgentMan(4,5,6)` would you tell me how should I do that?  @SecretAgentMan

Comment: @alieskandari, the command `A(k,:)` returns the k-th row of `A`.  You can modify the code if you don't want to use MATLAB's "all-columns" shortcut ( the colon, : ).  The code I posted seems to give you the answer you seek when I run it. Are you wanting it in row instead of column?

Comment: Thank you so much... I edited it and it works .... I really appreciate for your kindness. And I really sorry for bothered you and take your time.